# How to generate this mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have this database table named messages:

```
Column          Type    

global_ref_id   int(12)          
to              int(12)      
from            int(12)      
message         text             
status          int(1)   
viewed          int(1)
```

where global_ref_id is id of messages (foreign key from table events), to is user id of user who received message, from is user id  of user who send the message.

I want to generate a query which gives me result displaying last message from each user to a user (say whose user_id is 192) also giving total number of messages from each user to user 192.

Till now I came up with this query to get results:

```
> SELECT messages.*
>                 FROM messages, events
>                 WHERE events.global_id = messages.global_ref_id
>                 AND to = 192
>                 GROUP BY messages.from
>                 ORDER BY events.event_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the minimum of your query do the following (Untested by the way):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT messages.*,events.event_time, COUNT(messages.from) as "Total Messages Between Users"
    FROM messages, events
    WHERE events.global_id = messages.global_ref_id
    AND messages.to = 192
    GROUP BY messages.from
    ORDER BY messages.from
)
AS EVENTS
ORDER BY events.event_time
LIMIT 1;
```

The `LIMIT 1` will display only the last message, get rid if you want all messages instead of only the last.

Comment: it working good but it is not giving the latest message between the users instead it is displaying the oldest message or the first message between the users

Comment: Change DESC for ASC on your ORDER BY (or simply get rid of it). I've edited the post. Now it should work

Comment: Changing to ASC in ORDER BY will only rearrange the result order.But will not change the result.

Comment: If you are using `LIMIT 1` it will fetch the first line of your result, which should be the latest if you are ordering by events.event_time. If still it doesn't work. Would you mind to post your `events` table description?

Comment: What I want is latest message from each user not the last user who send the message.Say if 9 users send messages to 192 then the last message from each user should be displayed

Comment: I want result similar to that in facebook when we see messages in fb it shows last message from each of your friend

Comment: The thing is: You have different ORDER BY and GROUP BY expressions. It's one case where ORDER BY can not index it properly, check this for reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: There's however another way, but I don't think you'll like it. Just wait for my edition

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c68dc/1 please look at this here as you can see in results oldest message is shown not the latest I need latest message to be shown even if I change ASC to DESC or vice-versa only order will be changed

Answer (score 0):

Result displaying last message from each user to a user (say whose user_id is 192)

```
SELECT 
    messages.message as 'Last Message'
FROM 
    messages, events
WHERE 
    events.global_id = messages.global_ref_id
AND to = 192
GROUP BY messages.from
ORDER BY events.event_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Total number of messages from each user to user 192

```
SELECT 
    messages.*, COUNT(messages.from) as "Total number of Messages to User"
FROM 
    messages, events
WHERE 
    events.global_id = messages.global_ref_id
AND to = 192
GROUP BY messages.from
ORDER BY events.event_time DESC
```

Comment: But all these queries are displaying the oldest message between users not the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, I'm only new to MySQL though.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0586/8

m.`to`and m.`from` are in back ticks as they are reserved words.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for this but as you can see in the results the messages between 192 and 578 the result is not displaying the latest message which is 'This is the final test message' instead it is displaying an older message I want the latest messages to be displayed.

Comment: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c68dc/1 please look at this here as you can see in results oldest message is shown not the latest I need latest message to be shown even if I change ASC to DESC or vice-versa only order will be changed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
m.global_ref_id,
m.`to`,
m.`from`,
m.message,
m.status,
m.viewed
FROM messages m
WHERE m.global_ref_id = (SELECT max(i.global_ref_id)
                         FROM messages igroup
                         WHERE i.`to` = m.`to`
                         AND i.`from` = m.`from`);
```

Will give you the most recent message; getting the total will be another query...

```
SELECT
m.`to`,
m.`from`,
count(*)
FROM messages m
GROUP BY m.`to`, m.`from`
```

merging the output from these two queries is another problem!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with the answer I don't know how good this query is but it is working for me:-

```
SELECT messages.global_ref_id,
messages.`to`,
messages.`from`,
messages.message,
messages.status,
messages.viewed,
events.event_time,
count_table.msg_count as `total Number of messages`
FROM
messages
INNER JOIN
(select max(global_ref_id) as ref_id, count(*) msg_count from messages group by `from`)
as count_table
on (messages.global_ref_id = count_table.ref_id)
INNER JOIN events
on (events.global_id = messages.global_ref_id)
where messages.`to` = 192
order by events.global_id DESC
```

Thanks everybody...

Comment: I have tried it but it's not the way it should display